# How to fetch data from a joined query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a joined query in PHP, which I wanted to join 2 databases VIA the user ID, but I want to be able to fetch data from both tables **(users & user_stats)**, although it's not letting me output any data from the `user_stats` table, which is leaving me to believe there's a error in my query..

Hence this being my first time using joined tables, could someone please guide me in the correct direction, so far I have:

```
$getMembers3 = dbquery("SELECT users.id, users.look, users.username
                        FROM users
                        JOIN user_stats
                        ON users.id = user_stats.id
                        WHERE users.rank < 2 ORDER BY user_stats.Respect DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Which I am trying to fetch Respects from `user_stats` VIA:

```
while ($member2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getMembers3))
    {
     echo $member2['user_stats.Respect'] . '<br>';
     echo $member2['username'] . '<br>';
    }
```

Although it allows me to view their username from the users table, it won't allow me to view the user_stats.Respect. If someone could enlighten me in the right direction that'd be fantastic.

Comment: FYI, you should stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are officially deprecated and removed as of PHP7.

Comment: Are you sure it would be `ON users.id = user_stats.id` and not `ON users.id = user_stats.user_id` check your table again ?

Comment: Unknown column 'user_stats.user_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: share table schema ?

Comment: Both tables contain "id" to verify the user. All I need to grab from user_stats is "Respects"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always get confused when selecting from mutliple tables and this is how I generally resolve my confusion:

```
$getMembers3 = dbquery("SELECT users.id as id, users.look as look, users.username as username, user_stats.Respect as respect
                        FROM users
                        JOIN user_stats
                        ON users.id = user_stats.id
                        WHERE users.rank < 2 ORDER BY user_stats.Respect DESC LIMIT 10");
```

This way you know what the column names are expected to be. Sidenote, the result set will not have dots in the array keys.

Then you can access results from:

```
while ($member2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getMembers3))
    {
     echo $member2['respect'] . '<br>';
     echo $member2['username'] . '<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query adding the field in your select statement:

```
$getMembers3 = dbquery("SELECT users.id, users.look, users.username,user_stats.Respect 
                        FROM users
                        JOIN user_stats
                        ON users.id = user_stats.id
                        WHERE users.rank < 2 ORDER BY user_stats.Respect DESC LIMIT 10");
```

As a side note you are using a deprecated api to access database that have been removed in PHP 7. Consider switching to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: This still isn't showing the user_stats.Respect (yes I noted that stat was suppose to be stats), and I am aware of the deprecation, but I am not going to update my whole content management system to PDO as of yet.

Comment: Then there is an issue in the query logic. Show the table structure editing your query please

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking for. users.id, users.look is what I need to pull from the users table, and all I need to pull from the user_stats table is "Respect", if this makes sense.